# Error trapping with regex

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have the following dataframe

```
ColumnA=c("Kuala Lumpur Sector 2 new","old Jakarta Sector31",    "Sector 9, 7 Hong Kong","Jakarta new Sector22")
```

and am extracting the Sector number to a separate column

```
gsub(".*Sector ?([0-9]+).*","\\1",ColumnA)
```

Is there a more elegant way to capture errors if 'Sector' does not appear on one line than an if else statement?

If the word 'Sector' does not appear on one line I simply want to set the value of that row to blank.

I thought of using str_detect first to see if 'Sector' was there TRUE/FALSE, but this is quite an ugly solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note: Technically speaking, `ColumnA` is a character vector, not a data.frame. And this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194088/extracting-number-from-text-string-referencing-specific-text) is the reference.

Comment: I guess you want this: `ColumnA=c("Kuala Lumpur 2 new","old Jakarta Sector31",    "Sector 9, 7 Hong Kong","Jakarta new Sector22")
gsub("^(?:.*Sector ?([0-9]+).*|.*)$","\\1",ColumnA)`. See [demo](http://ideone.com/ObaZTF). Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the word 'Sector' does not appear on one line I simply want to set the value of that row to blank.

To achieve that, use alternation operator `|`:

```
ColumnA=c("Kuala Lumpur 2 new","old Jakarta Sector31",    "Sector 9, 7 Hong Kong","Jakarta new Sector22")
gsub("^(?:.*Sector ?([0-9]+).*|.*)$","\\1",ColumnA)
```

Result: `[1] ""   "31" "9"  "22"` (as `Kuala Lumpur 2 new` has no `Sector`, the second part with no capturing group matched the whole string).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ObaZTF)

Comment: Glad it works for you. If you also find galapagos' answer useful, you can upvote that one, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
as.vector(sapply(str_extract(ColumnA, "(?<=Sector\\s{0,10})([0-9]+)"),function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),'')))
```

I think this is what you need.